# Can't get file in Post-Controller from input in Phtml

Tags: phtml, file-upload

I have a file-input field in my pthml and would like to use it to upload picture files.

```
[...]
                <div class="field file">
                    <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Attach a picture')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="pictureUpload"
                               id="pictureUpload"
                               type="file"
                               class="input-file"
                               accept="image/*"
                               value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
[...]
```

My Post-Controller works with all other inputs but not with the file.
I tried getting it via `$this->getRequest()->getFiles();` and checked `$_FILES` but it remains empty.
Is there another component involved that I'm missing?

My Controller extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` and implements `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check with below example your `form` all attributes is same like this.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form contact" action="Your action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ............
    ............
</form>
```

This `Form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"` is needed when you use `file input` in your phtml file.

In controller you can try below code for get input data.

```
$files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
```

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: That is exactly what was missing. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Most welcome buddy 